# Can't copy Share link from link box after a post has been edited

Tags: bug, status-norepro, live-refresh

Pretty sure that's what happening here. I was trying to share a post via the `link` box, but ctrl+c gave me the error sound, and didn't copy the text. I looked up and noticed the post had an update the Live Refresh was waiting to show me. After letting the post update, the link worked again

Comment: Maybe the focus went somewhere else when the live refresh pushed that update so you tried to copy without anything actually selected - try to reproduce it then focus the URL again. In such case it's not really a major bug.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to reproduce this - this bug could have been fixed when we implemented the new share dialog.

[image]

Comment: On the URL in that post, why does it say `http://local.so.com/...`? If I go to that URL, my browser says it can't find the page. Am I misreading it?

Comment: Nope - that's what we use when developing Stack Overflow locally.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. I was confused because a while ago, I went to so.com, and it was some Chinese search engine.

Comment: @HobbitHole Yeah it still is a Chinese search engine.